# Some but not all of fetch data is undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load JSON data via a call in the constructor and then pass that data to a series of child elements. The problem is that all the data seems to load *except* for one item (`picture.url`). All the other info loads and displays properly, but I get an error when trying to load the picture value - it is a nested JSON object with two fields, `comment` and `url`.

Here is an example of a normal JSON response:

```
{
  "id": 001,
  "name": "Harry",
  "online_status": "OFFLINE",
  "picture": {
      "comment": SOMECOMMENT,
       "url": SOMEURL
  },
  "last_login": SOMEDATEOBJECT,
}
```

And here is my code:

**TilesContainer.js** - where the fetch call is made

```
class TilesContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { users: [], };
    this.getUsers = this.getUsers.bind(this);
    this.tiles = this.tiles.bind(this);
    this.getUsers("http://localhost:3000/api/search?length=32");
  }

  getUsers(usersLink) {
    fetch(usersLink)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJson => {
      let users = myJson.items;
      this.setState({
        users: users,
      })
    })
  }

tiles() {

    return (
      this.state.users.map(user => (
         <Tile key={user.id}  id={user.id} name={user.name} lastLogin={user.last_login} 
        onlineStatus={user.online_status} pictureLink={user.picture.url} />
      ))
    )
 }

  render(){
      return (
        <div id="tiles-container"
             className="tiles-container">
              {this.tiles()}
        </div>
      )
    }


}

export default TilesContainer
```

**Tiles.js** - where the data is passed as props

```
class Tile extends Component {


  render() {

      let lastLoginDisplay = "";
      let lastLogin = Date.parse(this.props.lastLogin);
      let now = new Date();

      let timeDifferenceInMs = now.getTime() - lastLogin;
      let timeDifferenceInHours = Math.floor(timeDifferenceInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      let timeDifferenceInDays = Math.floor(timeDifferenceInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

      if (this.props.onlineStatus === "OFFLINE") {
        if (timeDifferenceInHours <= 24 ) {
          if (timeDifferenceInHours === 1) {
            lastLoginDisplay = "Last seen " + timeDifferenceInHours.toString() + " hour ago";
          } else {
            lastLoginDisplay = "Last seen " + timeDifferenceInHours.toString() + " hours ago";
          }
        } else {
          if (timeDifferenceInDays === 1) {
            lastLoginDisplay = "Last seen " + timeDifferenceInDays.toString() + " day ago";
          } else {
            lastLoginDisplay = "Last seen " + timeDifferenceInDays.toString() + " days ago";
          }
        }
      } else {
        lastLoginDisplay = this.props.onlineStatus;
      }

       return (
         <div id={this.props.id} className='tile'>
             <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
             <img src={this.props.pictureLink} alt={"userPic"}/>
             <h3><span>{lastLoginDisplay}</span></h3>
         </div>
       )
     }

}

export default Tile
```

And here is a screenshot of the error message I get when it fails to load: 
[image: Screenshot of error message]

Granted, when I tried passing the whole user object as one prop and then console.logging the url, I was able to! It would output a whole list of URLs and then it would produce the same error...Not sure if this is about how I'm trying to load the data (i.e. the problem is asynchronous). Like I said, all the other data fields load and are successfully passed as props, it's only the picture field giving this trouble. Thanks.

EDIT: Output of the debugger showing me that one of the items in user data array was missing the `picture` field, thus it was coming up undefined.
[image]

Comment: Your code seems to be outdated or missing in the example. In *TilesContainer.js* you call `Tile` with only 2 props, `key` and `info` but the error shows more props such as `pictureLink` and `lastLogin`

Comment: Hi there that was a copy/paste error - should be correct now, thanks for your help

Comment: Stick a debugger inside the tiles map function and tell us what `user` is.

Comment: What I don't get is how the mapping function can resolve user.name and user.online_status but user.picture appears to be undefined. Are you sure the field is actually there in your API response?

Comment: If your response is just that `object` you should wrapper that within an array `this.setState({ users: [users] })`. But there are lots of issues to figure out there, call your side-effect on `componentDidMount`. And for security, ever before you map an array you validate `this.state.users && this.state.users.map(...)`

Comment: Hi @JimmyBreck-McKye yes there is a user.picture field returned in every one of the API calls. Really scratching my head here. What sort of debugger can I put inside the map function? I'm not able to insert `console.log(user)` after the return. @JmLavoier I tried wrapping within an array as per `this.setState({ users: [users] })` but got the same error. The response is normally an array of several different items of that same object (i.e. id #s 001, 002, 003, etc).

Comment: Honestly your best bet is just to use a debugger. Chrome will let you break on any uncaught exceptions - when that happens, see what the stack vars are in the user() mapping function and specifically the state of the user param

Comment: Alternatively, refactor your user mapping function to have a proper function body, and stick a debugger statement above the expression

Comment: I've tried adding an example in my answer, but I'm typing on the go and this makes it hard to provide a code sample

Comment: Ok good news and bad news. Bad news is there is actually one field in my array of return objects that is missing the `picture` field. I will now try and write a way to handle this exception. The good news is I have a good idea of how to move forward, this is my first time using a debugger and so thanks for the tip! This is part of a job hiring process coding challenge and it might be that they're giving incomplete data just to see how I handle it. I'm adding a screenshot of the debugger output in case anyone is curious. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, marvellous. Can you accept my answer below? Good luck with the interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you confident that the value of picture is not actually undefined in one of your API responses?

Your mapping function seems to recieve a User object just fine - it can resolve user.name and user.offline_status, for example (I am fairly sure these will be evaluated in left-right order as JSX props). You aren't merging objects or doing any strange mutations. So the most obvious possibility is that, as the error message says, user.picture really IS undefined.

The easiest way to check is to open the network tab in your device tools and inspect the JSON payload that comes back from the server. I strongly suspect that a field you thought was guaranteed is actually optional.

EDIT

If you need to debug the tiles mapping function, try

```
tiles() {

return (
  this.state.users.map(user => {
    debugger;
    return <Tile key={user.id}  id={user.id} name={user.name} lastLogin={user.last_login} 
    onlineStatus={user.online_status} pictureLink={user.picture.url} />
  });
 }
```

(Sorry, it is very hard to type out code on a phone)